# Clamping by Mapwidth in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, clamp

For Smooth touch in unity but i dont know where should i use Mathf.Clamp to restrict the movement of player in the map.

Got It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the position calculation and add a certain hard limit like e.g.

```
public float minX;
public float minY;
public float maxX;
public float maxY;

public float playerSpeed;

[SerializeField] private Camera _mainCamera;

void Awake()
{
    if(!_mainCamera) _mainCamera = Camera.main;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        var touchPosition = touch.position;

        var currentPosition = transform.position;
        var speed = playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // get this objects position in screen (pixel) space
        var screenPosition = _mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

        if (touchPosition.x < screenPosition.x)
        {
            currentPosition.x -= speed;
        }
        else if (touchPosition.x > screenPosition.x)
        {
            currentPosition.x += speed;
        }

        currentPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentPosition.x, minX, maxX);

        if (touchPosition.y < screenPosition.y)
        {
            currentPosition.y -= speed;
        }
        else if (touchPosition.y > screenPosition.y)
        {
            currentPosition.y += speed;
        }

        currentPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp(currentPosition.y, minX, maxX);

        transform.position = currentPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you So much..this script works like a charm, instead of getting screenwidth you took its position into main camera and then tranform position right?

Comment: @LuciferM I do both things independently. For comparing the touch position I just converted the current position into screen space since you are only interested in if touch is higher or lower but not the exact delta. This is easier than converting the other way round since than you always have to make sure you use the correct distance from the camera